# Detect hit inside a closed SVG polygon with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, point-in-polygon

In a barebones test, I have created an SVG pentagon with a rectangle that fits it exactly. I run `svg.checkIntersection(pentagon, rect)` to test if a 1x1 rect is within the area of the pentagon.

This returns `true` for any point within the bounding rect of the pentagon. How can I get it to return `false` except when the point is actually within the pentagonal shape itself?

Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hit SVG</title> 
</head>
<body>
<!-- Pentagon with a side of 100px -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="pentagon">
    <polygon
points="
80.9016994375,0
0,58.7785252292
30.9016994375,153.8841768588
130.9016994375,153.8841768588
161.8033988750,58.7785252292
"
style="stroke: #eee"></polygon>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<!-- Rectangle with a golden ratio -->
<svg class="container" width="324" height="308" onclick="hitTest(event)">
  <rect width="324" height="308" style="fill: #ccc"></rect>
  <rect width="162" height="154" style="fill: #999"></rect>

  <svg style="fill:#333" viewBox="0 0 162 154", width="162" height="154">
    <use xlink:href="#pentagon"></use>
  </svg>
</svg>

<script>
function hitTest(event) {
  var svg = event.currentTarget
  var pentagon = document.querySelector("use")

  var rect = svg.createSVGRect()
  rect.x = event.offsetX
  rect.y = event.offsetY
  rect.width = rect.height = 1
  hit = svg.checkIntersection(pentagon, rect)
  console.log(hit)
}
</script>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nv5ndt4q/

Comment: There is a Chrome Issue for this behavior http://crbug.com/370012 and FireFox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=501421